# Assigning a ruby hash by map do where values don't consistantly exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an map that I have to assemble before using...

```
mailList = Customers.map do |customer|
{
  :username => customer.name,
  :email => customer.email,
  :last_ip_v4 => customer.ipv4,
  :last_ip_v6 => customer.ipv6
}
end
```

This works for a number of test users, but not all users have a last ipv4 AND a last ipv6. When they don't, ruby errors out, but I'd rather it just assign a nil. How do I do that?

Comment: You code block missing `end` but I assume you have it in your local, the code seems to be fine but can you share us your execution and error output?

Comment: Can you show the error? Also, where are you getting `Customers` from?

Comment: @MarkMerritt /bundle/gems/activemodel-4.1.16/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing' is the error I'm getting. And I have output right before and after that code, so I know that's where it's breaking.

Comment: @Coco I added in the end. Yes, it's in my local.

Comment: what is `Customers`? is it array of object or class name?

Comment: @Coco array I believe, although I've had a dickens of a time finding an easy way to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you are sure that this line,

```
mailList = Customers.map do |customer|
```

will work fine (may be incase of using a wrong convention), then try to check the nil cases for ipv4 and ipv6 and construct the list as,

```
    mailList = construct_list Customers
    def construct_list data
      list = []
      hash ={}
      data.map do |customer|
        hash[:username] = customer.name
        hash[:email] = customer.email
        customer.ipv4.nil? ? hash[:last_ip_v4] = nil : hash[:last_ip_v4] = customer.ipv4
        customer.ipv6.nil? ? hash[:last_ip_v6] = nil : hash[:last_ip_v6] = customer.ipv6
        list << hash
      end
      list
    end
```

Though it may not be optimal, it will help you for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Even if ipv4 and ipv6 are nil, it should not throw error. I think the syntax here is incorrect or `Customers` is nil. Try this way:

```
mailList = Customer.all.map do |customer|
  {
    username: customer.name,
    email: customer.email,
    last_ip_v4: customer.ipv4,
    last_ip_v6: customer.ipv6
  }
end
```